# How can I tell if a Borderlands 2 matchmaking party requires DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

By now, most players who have played BL2 have finished the main storyline and are pretty much visiting the other DLC.  When I try to join a match, however, whether it be a quick match or a server browser, it seems I get kicked out of each game because I don't own any DLC, and the people on that server have it and are in it.

Are there any ways for me to identify which servers are playing in DLC maps?

Comment: its annoying for me too, i'm too cheap to buy the season pass, waiting for it to go on sale :P

Comment: steam sale, y u no put dlc on sale?

Comment: @Retrosaur: y u no pre-order season pass?

Comment: @MBraedley rule of the cheap gamer says wait 2 weeks after game comes out to buy it half off on steam :P

Comment: I'm still waiting for that level cap DLC and hoping that all the other DLC gets put on sale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can avoid that is to make your own online game that people can join. It may not be as fun initially, but at least it will scale back the other person's game to match yours if they do have DLC.